# How to delete all files in all sub-folders except those whose filename is 'whatever.jpg' in PHP?

Tags: php, file, directory, filesystems, delete-file

What's the **fastest** way to delete **all** files in **all** sub-folders **except** those whose filename is 'whatever.jpg' in PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by **fastest** ?

Comment: do you have a slow way you want to share?

Comment: i wouldn't bother using php, the os has better options: find ! -name filename -type f -delete

Comment: Regarding **fastest**, please see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120287/directory-to-array-with-php/2120496#2120496

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use iterators? This is tested:

```
function run($baseDir, $notThis)
{
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($baseDir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY) as $file) {
        if ($file->isFile() && $file->getFilename() != $notThis) {
            @unlink($file->getPathname());
        }
    }
}

run('/my/path/base', 'do_not_cancel_this_file.jpg');
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks.  What's the difference between using "@unlink" and just "unlink"?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what youre looking for, `$but` is an array holding exceptions.
Not sure if its *the fastest*, but its the most common way for directory iteration.

```
function rm_rf_but ($what, $but)
{
    if (!is_dir($what) && !in_array($what,$but))
        @unlink($what);
    else
    {
        if ($dh = opendir($what))
        {
            while(($item = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {
                if (in_array($item, array_merge(array('.', '..'),$but)))
                    continue;
                rm_rf_but($what.'/'.$item, $but);
            }
        }

        @rmdir($what); // remove this if you dont want to delete the directory
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
rm_rf_but('.', array('notme.jpg','imstayin.png'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
function run($baseDir) {
    $files = scandir("{$baseDir}/");
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $path = "{$badeDir}/{$file}";
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            if(is_dir($path)) {
                run($path);
            } elseif(is_file($path)) {
                if(/* here goes you filtermagic */) {
                    unlink($path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
run('.');
```

Comment: Note `scandir()` was added in PHP5.